# Kivy installation error in Ubuntu

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to installing the kivy package.
The installation guide says to do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

and shows this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-kivy : Depends: python-kivy-bin (= 1.9.2-0~daily0+201609211917-3732-pkg135~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to do: sudo apt-get install python-kivy python-kivy-bin
Shows:

```
python-kivy-bin : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsdl2-image-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Comment: The problem is that you have added a non-Ubuntu source. That non-Ubuntu source is providing your system with a non-Ubuntu python-kivy package that *conflicts* with other software on your system. Delete that non-Ubuntu source.

Comment: my non-ubuntu source is the official kivy ppa.
I did like the official installation guide told me to do:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update

Comment: Have you told kivy that their PPA broke your Ubuntu system? They may not know, or they may have a suggestion how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below Instructions

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy

sudo apt-get install -f   # in case any issue 

sudo apt-get install python-kivy #fire again after clear dependanceis issues.
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install kivy
sudo pip install kivy --upgrade
```

Kivy world is wounderful for GUI Apps Development.